# The simplest organism that can learn?

Tags: brain, learning

What is the simplest organism that was observed to learn: change its behavior permanently in response to some event/stimuli in a way that this change persists even if the event does not happen again?

Comment: the real problem is defining  and testing learning.

Comment: Judging from the first source brought by Bryan Krause, the definition I had in mind was associative learning.

Comment: which may be possible for even a single celled organism. Bryan Krause provided a good link to possible associative learning in amoebae.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it is definitively the simplest, but the simplest organism with a nervous system that has been studied extensively is probably [C. elegans](http://learnmem.cshlp.org/content/17/4/191.long), which is definitely able to learn.

Some basic learning abilities have also been shown in [amoebae](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.100.018101).

---

References:

- Ardiel, E. L., & Rankin, C. H. (2010). An elegant mind: learning and
  memory in Caenorhabditis elegans. Learning & Memory, 17(4), 191-201.
- Saigusa, T., Tero, A., Nakagaki, T., & Kuramoto, Y. (2008). Amoebae
  anticipate periodic events. Physical review letters, 100(1), 018101.